# Compare data between two Azure SQL DB's

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-sql-reporting

I have a requirement where I have to compare data between two tables from two different Azure SQL DB's. Both the database have same schema so i just need to compare the data. What are all the options i have since i cant do a cross SQL querying in Azure SQL? Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first try the [tablediff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/tablediff-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) utility, perhaps running on an Azure VM.